# scheduler and stack

Tags: stm32f4, rtos, stack

i develop my own scheduler on stm32f407 board

i have different queues of tasks with different priorities and frequencies

i want to mange stack operations myself when in SysTick_Handler  event each 10ms

where to start from in push and pop operations

should i define own stack or what?

any good article tutorial or example if you have???
thanks in advance..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Typically each task would have its own private stack.  You save and restore the stack pointer when you switch tasks in your `SysTick_Handler`.

I also like to have a separate stack for the task switcher - basically treat that as a separate task as well - though you can use the default system stack if you wish.

Comment: could you please explain " task would have its own private stack"
where and how to access it,i use kiel v5

Comment: It's your task management system - it's up to you how to allocate and manage the stack. A system I wrote has a single static allocation of RAM which is sliced into chunks, one for each task's stack. When you create the task you allocate the stack space for it and set it's stack pointer to that memory location. How you do that depends on how your task manager works.

Comment: i have a 3 queues 
each one has N tasks
q1..runs every 10ms until finish all it tasks
q2..each 200 ms in free time after q1 finish between q1 runs
q3..runs in the rest of the 200ms after q2 finish and between q1 also
each task is a simple function
each queue is a static table of those excutable functions
i didnt understand waht you wrote about task magement

Comment: That's nice. Do you have any TCBs?

Comment: yes but not in the standard form we read in books

Comment: while a task is running in q2
i will be interrupted by systick handler
running all q1
then return back to this interrupted task
it is so complicated 
i want to save the current position for each queue in seprate stack,how???

Comment: Every task has a context, yes? Or do you just store the context of the queue and only ever have 3 concurrent tasks, one per queue, and when one task finishes it moves to the next in the queue?

Comment: when one task finishes it moves to the next in the queue

Comment: Ok, so each queue will have its own stack then.

Comment: yes i want but how

Comment: How do you want to? Remember - it's your system, so how you do it is entirely up to you.  Allocate some RAM somehow. Store the SP somewhere (the queue's TCB). Change the SP when you change the queue.

Comment: dear sir,i know all that theoretical stuff very well
i will save stack pointer register in an memory area with all genral purpose registers and push pop it again
should i do that using asm in my C code usin push and pop operation only,no recomendation
if u have any piece of code to simplify it to me i will be happy

Comment: another question ,for testing i but on of my tasks in an infinite loop,but systick_handler stop interupting it,i dont know why??

Comment: Neither do I. Only you can answer those two last questions, since you wrote the system. I don't have the slightest clue how your system works or what your code is like.

Answer (score 0):

**The Definitive Guide to ARM Cortex M3 and Cortex-M4 **CHAPTER 10 OS Support Features*** amazing book i had found and want to share this working example with you

```
#include "stm32f4xx.h"
// Keil::Device:STM32Cube HAL:Common

    #define LED0 (1<<7)
    #define LED1 (1<<8)
    #define LED2 (1<<9)
    #define LED3 (1<<10)

    /* Macros for word accesses */
    #define HW32_REG(ADDRESS) (*((volatile unsigned long *)(ADDRESS)))
    /* Use Breakpoint to stop when error is detected
    (KEIL MDK specific intrinsic) */
    /* it can be changed to while(1) XXif needed */
    #define stop_cpu __breakpoint(0)
    void LED_initialize(void); // Initialize LED
    void task0(void); // Toggle LED0
    void task1(void); // Toggle LED1
    void task2(void); // Toggle LED2
    void task3(void); // Toggle LED3
    // Event to tasks
    volatile uint32_t systick_count=0;
    // Stack for each task (8Kbytes each - 1024 x 8 bytes)
    long long task0_stack[1024], task1_stack[1024],
    task2_stack[1024], task3_stack[1024];
    // Data use by OS
    uint32_t curr_task=0; // Current task
    uint32_t next_task=1; // Next task
    uint32_t PSP_array[4]; // Process Stack Pointer for each task
    // -------------------------------------------------------------
    // Start of main program
    int main(void)
    {
    SCB->CCR |= SCB_CCR_STKALIGN_Msk; // Enable double word stack alignment
    //(recommended in Cortex-M3 r1p1, default in Cortex-M3 r2px and Cortex-M4)
    LED_initialize();
    // Starting the task scheduler
    // Create stack frame for task0
    PSP_array[0] = ((unsigned int) task0_stack)
    + (sizeof task0_stack) - 16*4;
    HW32_REG((PSP_array[0] + (14<<2))) = (unsigned long) task0;
    // initial Program Counter
    HW32_REG((PSP_array[0] + (15<<2))) = 0x01000000; // initial xPSR
    // Create stack frame for task1
    PSP_array[1] = ((unsigned int) task1_stack)
    + (sizeof task1_stack) - 16*4;
    HW32_REG((PSP_array[1] + (14<<2))) = (unsigned long) task1;
    // initial Program Counter
    HW32_REG((PSP_array[1] + (15<<2))) = 0x01000000; // initial xPSR
    // Create stack frame for task2
    PSP_array[2] = ((unsigned int) task2_stack)
    + (sizeof task2_stack) - 16*4;
    HW32_REG((PSP_array[2] + (14<<2))) = (unsigned long) task2;
    // initial Program Counter
    HW32_REG((PSP_array[2] + (15<<2))) = 0x01000000; // initial xPSR
    // Create stack frame for task3
    PSP_array[3] = ((unsigned int) task3_stack)
    + (sizeof task3_stack) - 16*4;
    HW32_REG((PSP_array[3] + (14<<2))) = (unsigned long) task3;
    // initial Program Counter
    HW32_REG((PSP_array[3] + (15<<2))) = 0x01000000; // initial xPSR
    curr_task = 0; // Switch to task #0 (Current task)
    __set_PSP((PSP_array[curr_task] + 16*4)); // Set PSP to topof task 0 stack
    NVIC_SetPriority(PendSV_IRQn, 0xFF); // Set PendSV to lowest possible priority
    SysTick_Config(168000); // 1000 Hz SysTick interrupton 168MHz core clock
    __set_CONTROL(0x3); // Switch to use Process Stack, unprivilegedstate
    __ISB(); // Execute ISB after changing CONTROL (architecturalrecommendation)
    task0(); // Start task 0
    while(1){
    stop_cpu;// Should not be here
    };
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    void task0(void) // Toggle LED #0
    { while (1) {
    if (systick_count & 0x80) {GPIOE->BSRRL = LED0;} // Set LED 0
    else {GPIOE->BSRRH = LED0;} // Clear LED 0
    };
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    void task1(void) // Toggle LED #1
    { while (1) {
    if (systick_count & 0x100){GPIOE->BSRRL = LED1;} // Set LED 1
    else {GPIOE->BSRRH = LED1;} // Clear LED 1
    };
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    void task2(void) // Toggle LED #2
    { while (1) {
    if (systick_count & 0x200){GPIOE->BSRRL = LED2;} // Set LED 2
    else {GPIOE->BSRRH = LED2;} // Clear LED 2
    };
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    void task3(void) // Toggle LED #3
    { while (1) {
    if (systick_count & 0x400){GPIOE->BSRRL = LED3;} // Set LED 3
    else {GPIOE->BSRRH = LED3;} // Clear LED 3
    };
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    __asm void PendSV_Handler(void)
    { // Context switching code
    // Simple version - assume No floating point support
    // -------------------------
    // Save current context

      MRS R0, PSP // Get current process stack pointer value
      STMDB R0!,{R4-R11} // Save R4 to R11 in task stack (8 regs)
      LDR R1,=__cpp(&curr_task)
      LDR R2,[R1] // Get current task ID
      LDR R3,=__cpp(&PSP_array)
      STR R0,[R3, R2, LSL #2] // Save PSP value into PSP_array
      // -------------------------
      // Load next context
      LDR R4,=__cpp(&next_task)
      LDR R4,[R4] // Get next task ID
      STR R4,[R1] // Set curr_task = next_task
      LDR R0,[R3, R4, LSL #2] // Load PSP value from PSP_array
      LDMIA R0!,{R4-R11} // Load R4 to R11 from task   stack (8 regs)
      MSR PSP, R0 // Set PSP to next task
      BX LR // Return
      ALIGN 4
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    void SysTick_Handler(void) // 1KHz
    { // Increment systick counter for LED blinking
    systick_count++;
    // Simple task round robin scheduler
    switch(curr_task) {
    case(0): next_task=1; break;
    case(1): next_task=2; break;
    case(2): next_task=3; break;
    case(3): next_task=0; break;
    default: next_task=0;
    stop_cpu;
    break; // Should not be here
    }
    if (curr_task!=next_task){ // Context switching needed
    SCB->ICSR |= SCB_ICSR_PENDSVSET_Msk; // Set PendSV to pending
    }
    return;
    }
    // ------------------------------------------------------------
    void LED_initialize(void)
    {
    // Configure LED outputs
    RCC->AHB1ENR |= RCC_AHB1ENR_GPIOEEN; // Enable Port D clock
    // Set pin 12, 13, 14, 15 as general purpose output mode(pull-push)
    GPIOE->MODER |= (GPIO_MODER_MODER7_0 |
    GPIO_MODER_MODER8_0 |
    GPIO_MODER_MODER9_0 |
    GPIO_MODER_MODER10_0 ) ;
    // GPIOE->OTYPER |= 0; // No need to change - use pull-push output
    GPIOE->OSPEEDR |= (GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR7 | // 100MHz operations
    GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR8 |
    GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR9 |
    GPIO_OSPEEDER_OSPEEDR10 );
    GPIOE->PUPDR = 0; // No pull up , no pull down
    return;
    }
```